# How to get rid of vertical offset in a table containing pictures?

Tags: tables, graphics, tabu

While trying to compose some kind of "wanted poster" (*Steckbrief*), I could not get rid of the vertical spacing LaTeX automatically introduces! Here's an MWE, which should work on Linux/Mac OS with `--shell-escape` enabled, though I needed to run it twice. I chose this variant since I didn't want to, and even couldn't upload personal photos.

```
% arara: pdflatex: {shell: yes}
% arara: pdflatex: {synctex: yes}

%% MWE to show a problem with pictures and text in tabu
\documentclass[paper=a4, oneside, fontsize=12pt]{scrartcl}

\usepackage[utf8]{inputenx}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{textcomp}
\usepackage[ngerman, english]{babel}
\parindent3mm

%% page geometry
\usepackage[a4paper, left=30mm, right=30mm,
 top=25mm, bottom=30mm]{geometry}

%% Selection of the fonts
\usepackage{bookman}
\usepackage[final]{microtype}
\overfullrule=1mm

%% to get 1.5 line spacing (Actually 1.25)
\usepackage{setspace}
\onehalfspacing
\setlength{\parindent}{5mm}

%% For the tables!
\usepackage{tabu, longtable, booktabs}
%\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage{graphicx}

\begin{document}

\title{MWE to show a problem with pictures and text in tabu}
\author{rotton}
\date{\today}

\maketitle

%% load the pictures from the web, if necessary
\IfFileExists{./DonEK.jpg}
{}
{
    \write18{wget -O ./DonEK.jpg https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/4/4f/KnuthAtOpenContentAlliance.jpg/406px-KnuthAtOpenContentAlliance.jpg?download}
}
\IfFileExists{./LeslieL.jpg}
{}
{
    \write18{wget -O ./LeslieL.jpg https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/5/50/Leslie_Lamport.jpg/377px-Leslie_Lamport.jpg?download}
}

%% Construction of the table itself
\tabulinesep=2pt
\extrarowsep=2pt
\begin{tabu}{X[c] X[2,l] X[2,l]}  %% 3 columns, width ratio 1:2:2
\toprule
\includegraphics[width=0.16\textwidth]{DonEK} Donald E. Knuth &
%\vspace{-6em}
\underline{Deutsch}
\begin{itemize}
\item Erfinder \textit{(und etwas mehr Text)}
\item von
\item \TeX
\end{itemize} &
\underline{English}
\begin{itemize}
\item Inventor \textit{(and some more text)}
\item of
\item \TeX
\end{itemize} \\
\midrule
\includegraphics[width=0.16\textwidth]{LeslieL} Leslie Lamport &
\underline{Deutsch}
\begin{itemize}
\item veröffentlichte Makros und Hilfsprogramme zum einfachen Umgang mit \TeX
\item ==> \LaTeX
\end{itemize} &
\underline{English}
\begin{itemize}
\item published macros and auxiliary programs for easy handling of \TeX
\item ==> \LaTeX
\end{itemize} \\
\bottomrule
\end{tabu}

\end{document}
```

The output looks like this:
[image: The red arrows (added manually) highlight the vertical space which I want to get rid of]

As you can see, there's a large vertical offset between the text in the second and third column, compared to the photos. I manually added some red arrows to highlight this. How to get rid of that space? I know I can manually introduce a negative vertical space (line 58, commented out), but that seems very unTeXnical to me!
(An alternative would be to use TikZ, but that's really another story.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add `\usepackage[export]{adjustbox}` and use

```
\includegraphics[width=0.16\textwidth,valign=t]{DonEK}
```

Example:

```
\documentclass[paper=a4, oneside, fontsize=12pt]{scrartcl}

\usepackage[utf8]{inputenx}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{textcomp}
\usepackage[ngerman, english]{babel}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage[export]{adjustbox}
\parindent3mm

%% page geometry
\usepackage[a4paper, left=30mm, right=30mm,
 top=25mm, bottom=30mm]{geometry}

%% Selection of the fonts
\usepackage{bookman}
\usepackage[final]{microtype}
\overfullrule=1mm

%% to get 1.5 line spacing (Actually 1.25)
\usepackage{setspace}
\onehalfspacing
\setlength{\parindent}{5mm}

%% For the tables!
\usepackage{tabu, longtable, booktabs}
%\usepackage{multirow}

\begin{document}

\title{MWE to show a problem with pictures and text in tabu}
\author{rotton}
\date{\today}

\maketitle

%% load the pictures from the web, if necessary
\IfFileExists{./DonEK.jpg}
{}
{
    \write18{wget -O ./DonEK.jpg https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/4/4f/KnuthAtOpenContentAlliance.jpg/406px-KnuthAtOpenContentAlliance.jpg?download}
}
\IfFileExists{./LeslieL.jpg}
{}
{
    \write18{wget -O ./LeslieL.jpg https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/5/50/Leslie_Lamport.jpg/377px-Leslie_Lamport.jpg?download}
}

%% Construction of the table itself
\tabulinesep=2pt
\extrarowsep=2pt
\begin{tabu}{X[c] X[2,l] X[2,l]}  %% 3 columns, width ratio 1:2:2
\toprule
\includegraphics[width=0.16\textwidth,valign=t]{DonEK} Donald E. Knuth &
%\vspace{-6em}
\underline{Deutsch}
\begin{itemize}
\item Erfinder \textit{(und etwas mehr Text)}
\item von
\item \TeX
\end{itemize} &
\underline{English}
\begin{itemize}
\item Inventor \textit{(and some more text)}
\item of
\item \TeX
\end{itemize} \\
\midrule
\includegraphics[width=0.16\textwidth,valign=t]{LeslieL} Leslie Lamport &
\underline{Deutsch}
\begin{itemize}
\item veröffentlichte Makros und Hilfsprogramme zum einfachen Umgang mit \TeX
\item ==> \LaTeX
\end{itemize} &
\underline{English}
\begin{itemize}
\item published macros and auxiliary programs for easy handling of \TeX
\item ==> \LaTeX
\end{itemize} \\
\bottomrule
\end{tabu}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You can do that with a simple `\raisebox` command:

```
\documentclass[paper=a4, oneside, fontsize=12pt]{scrartcl}

\usepackage[utf8]{inputenx}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{textcomp}
\usepackage[ngerman, english]{babel}
\parindent3mm

%% page geometry
\usepackage[a4paper, left=30mm, right=30mm,
 top=25mm, bottom=30mm]{geometry}

%% Selection of the fonts
\usepackage{bookman}
\usepackage[final]{microtype}
\overfullrule=1mm

%% to get 1.5 line spacing (Actually 1.25)
\usepackage{setspace}
\onehalfspacing
\setlength{\parindent}{5mm}

%% For the tables!
\usepackage{tabu, longtable, booktabs}
%\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage[demo]{graphicx}
\usepackage{multirow, makecell}

\begin{document}

\title{MWE to show a problem with pictures and text in tabu}
\author{rotton}
\date{\today}

\maketitle

%% load the pictures from the web, if necessary
\IfFileExists{./DonEK.jpg}
{}
{
    \write18{wget -O ./DonEK.jpg https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/4/4f/KnuthAtOpenContentAlliance.jpg/406px-KnuthAtOpenContentAlliance.jpg?download}
}
\IfFileExists{./LeslieL.jpg}
{}
{
    \write18{wget -O ./LeslieL.jpg https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/5/50/Leslie_Lamport.jpg/377px-Leslie_Lamport.jpg?download}
}

%% Construction of the table itself
\tabulinesep=2pt
\extrarowsep=2pt
\begin{tabu}{X[c] X[2,l] X[2,l]} %% 3 columns, width ratio 1:2:2
\toprule
\raisebox{-\height}[0pt][1.1\height]{\includegraphics[width=0.16\textwidth]{DonEK}} Donald E. Knuth &
%\vspace{-6em}
\underline{Deutsch}
\begin{itemize}
\item Erfinder \textit{(und etwas mehr Text)}
\item von
\item \TeX
\end{itemize} &
\underline{English}
\begin{itemize}
\item Inventor \textit{(and some more text)}
\item of
\item \TeX
\end{itemize} \\
\midrule
\raisebox{-\height}[0pt][1.1\height]{\includegraphics[width=0.16\textwidth]{LeslieL}} Leslie Lamport &
\underline{Deutsch}
\begin{itemize}
\item veröffentlichte Makros und Hilfsprogramme zum einfachen Umgang mit \TeX
\item ==> \LaTeX
\end{itemize} &
\underline{English}
\begin{itemize}
\item published macros and auxiliary programs for easy handling of \TeX
\item ==> \LaTeX
\end{itemize} \\
\bottomrule
\end{tabu}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Although the provided answers generally work, I ended up using TikZ for it's greater flexibility.
The somehow complicated-looking part with the `\mycasenode` command was necessary to get the text top-aligned.
Here's the code:

```
% arara: pdflatex: {shell: yes}
% arara: pdflatex: {synctex: yes}

%% MWE to show an alternative solution for a problem with pictures and text in tabu
\documentclass\[paper=a4, oneside, fontsize=12pt\]{scrartcl}

%% da Bericht auf Deutsch:
\usepackage\[utf8\]{inputenx}
\usepackage\[T1\]{fontenc}
\usepackage{textcomp}
\usepackage\[ngerman\]{babel}

%% page geometry
\usepackage\[a4paper, left=30mm, right=30mm,
 top=20mm, bottom=30mm\]{geometry}
%\usepackage{showframe}

%% Selection of the fonts
\usepackage{bookman}
\usepackage\[final\]{microtype}
\overfullrule=1mm

%% to get 1.5 line spacing (Actually 1.25)
\usepackage{setspace}
\onehalfspacing
\parindent0mm

%% For the tables!
\usepackage{tabu, longtable, booktabs}
%\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage\[export\]{adjustbox}

%% for the whole Tikz stuff
\usepackage{multicol}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes.multipart, shapes.misc, matrix, positioning}

\tikzstyle{fotobox}=\[
    rectangle, rounded corners=1mm,
    draw=black, very thick,
    text centered, text width=\textwidth*1/5\]

\tikzstyle{textbox}=\[
    rectangle, rounded corners=1mm,
    draw=black, very thick,
    text width=\textwidth*2/5-8mm\]

\tikzstyle{textbox2}=\[
    rectangle, rounded corners=1mm,
    draw=black, very thick,
    text width=\textwidth*2/5-6mm,
    append after command={node\[anchor=north west, minimum height=5mm, text width=\textwidth*2/5-6mm\]
    at (\tikzlastnode.north west){#1}}\]

\def\mycasenode(#1)\[#2\]#3;{\node (#1) \[textbox2={#3}, #2\] {};}

\newcommand*{\knuthDe}{
\underline{Deutsch}
\begin{itemize}
\item Erfinder \textit{(und etwas mehr Text)}
\item von
\item \TeX
\item TW: \the\textwidth
\end{itemize}
}

\newcommand*{\knuthEng}{
\underline{English}
\begin{itemize}
\item Inventor \textit{(and some more text)}
\item of
\item \TeX
\end{itemize}
}

\newcommand*{\lamportDe}{
\underline{Deutsch}
\begin{itemize}
\item veröffentlichte Makros und Hilfsprogramme zum einfachen Umgang mit \TeX
\item $\Longrightarrow$ \LaTeX
%\item Erhielt 2013 den Turing Award für seine Beiträge zur Theorie und Praxis verteilter und nebenläufiger Systeme
\end{itemize}
}

\newcommand*{\lamportEng}{
\underline{English}
\begin{itemize}
\item published macros and auxiliary programs for easy handling of \TeX
\item $\Longrightarrow$ \LaTeX
\end{itemize}
}

\begin{document}

\title{An alternative solution (using TikZ) for a problem with pictures and text in tabu}
\author{rotton}
\date{\today}

\maketitle

%% load the pictures from the web, if necessary
\IfFileExists{./DonEK.jpg}
{}
{
    \write18{wget -O ./DonEK.jpg https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/4/4f/KnuthAtOpenContentAlliance.jpg/406px-KnuthAtOpenContentAlliance.jpg?download}
}
\IfFileExists{./LeslieL.jpg}
{}
{
    \write18{wget -O ./LeslieL.jpg https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/5/50/Leslie_Lamport.jpg/377px-Leslie_Lamport.jpg?download}
}

%% Don E Knuth
\begin{tikzpicture}\[minimum height=55mm, node distance=5mm and 5mm\]
\node(bild1)\[fotobox, \] at (0,0)
{\includegraphics\[width=30mm\]{DonEK} \\ Donald E.\ Knuth};
%\node(knuthDe)\[textbox, text width=\textwidth-53mm, right=1mm of bild1.north east, anchor=north west\]{\knuthDe};
\mycasenode(knuthDe)\[right=1mm of bild1.north east, anchor=north west\]{\knuthDe};
\mycasenode()\[right=1mm of knuthDe.north east, anchor=north west\]{\knuthEng};
%\node()\[textbox, right=1mm of bende.north east, anchor=north west\]{\knuthEng};
%\end{tikzpicture}
%
%% Leslie Lamport
%\begin{tikzpicture}\[minimum height=55mm, node distance=0mm and 5mm\]
\node(bild2)\[fotobox, below=of bild1.south west, anchor=north west\]
{\includegraphics\[width=30mm\]{LeslieL} \\ Leslie Lamport};
\mycasenode(lamportDe)\[right=1mm of bild2.north east, anchor=north west\]{\lamportDe};
\mycasenode()\[right=1mm of lamportDe.north east, anchor=north west\]{\lamportEng};
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

[image: Alternative solution using TikZ]