# How to eliminate vertical offset before itemize in a table?

Tags: vertical-alignment, enumitem, tabu

Similar to [this earlier question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/289863/how-to-get-rid-of-vertical-offset-in-a-table-containing-pictures) of mine, but this time without pictures. I also found [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34919117), but appearantly the `topsep` option has no effect.
Consider the following MWE:

```
\documentclass[a4paper, 10pt]{scrartcl}

\usepackage[american]{babel}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenx}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{lmodern}

\usepackage{tabu, booktabs}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\setlist[itemize]{noitemsep, nosep, labelsep*=2em, labelindent=0em}

\begin{document}

\tabulinesep=5pt
\begin{tabu}{@{} >{\bfseries}X[l] X[2.5,l]}
\toprule
Main characters: &
%\vspace{-1.7em}
\begin{itemize}
\item Donald Duck
\item Daisy Duck
\item Huey, Dewey, and Louie
\item Scrooge McDuck
\item Ludwig Von Drake
\end{itemize} \\
\midrule
Relatives: &
%\vspace{-1.7em}
\begin{itemize}[topsep=0pt]
\item Duck family (Disney)
\item Clan McDuck
\end{itemize} \\
\midrule
First edition: & October 9, 1967 \\
\bottomrule
\end{tabu}

\end{document}
```

Which gives:
[image: tabu Itemize Offset]

The horizontal alignment of the bullet points with the text outside `itemize` ("October 9") is exactly how I want it to look like (although I've found this to be dependent on the hard coded `labelsep*` setting; not very TeX-like...).
But with or without `topsep=0pt`, the bullet points are not top-aligned inside their cell. Inserting a negative `\vspace` seems very clumsy to me, there must be a better way.

In short: How can the vertical offset be (easily) eliminated?

Comment: Have a look at http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/352597/124577

Comment: Did you try adding the optional argument `partopsep=0pt`?

Comment: @Bernard: I did, but it doesn't help. Just use `\begin{itemize}[partopsep=0pt]` on either of the two lists, and you will notice that the offset is bigger with than without this setting.

Answer (score 1):

Finally, I chose the following setting in the preamble:

```
\setlist[itemize]{leftmargin=*, itemsep=0pt, parsep=2pt, labelsep*=2em,
labelindent=0em, before=\vspace{-\dimexpr\baselineskip +2.6\partopsep}}
```

Not perfect, and still not very TeX-like, but it works.